# context free grammar for the language l={ a^n b^m c^p | p>=m>=n}

Tags: computer-science

I'm trying to write context free grammar for the language l={ a^n b^m c^p | p>=m>=n}

I know that i have to implement the options: for each b comes c and for each a come b and c and the option to add extra c's. I can't manage to write it though.
Any hlep would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be a programming question.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/619/how-can-i-prove-this-language-is-not-context-free

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about pure CS and not at a research level, and therefore is appropriate at cs.stackexchange.com.